# How to fix setAttribute Value is not getting displayed in UI

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

setAttribute value is setting the value in DOM but the value is not getting displayed in UI
[image]

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text to the question itself.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Approach to handle calendar in Selenium Webdriver

Step 1- Click on calendar

Step 2- Get all td of tables using findElements method

Step 3- using for loop get text of all elements

Step 4- using if else condition we will check specific date

Step 5- If date is matched then click and break the loop.

in this  [JQuery Date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and  using [findElements](http://learn-automation.com/difference-between-findelement-and-findelements-in-selenium-webdriver/) methods to find all the dates and then will get the text and will click on the respective date.

Try this code:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"searchWidgetCommon\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[5]/input")).click();

        List<WebElement> allDates=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fare_20190428\"]"));

        for(WebElement ele:allDates)
        {

            String date=ele.getText();

            if(date.equalsIgnoreCase("28"))
            {
                ele.click();
                break;
            }

        }
```